# Is there any documentation available for integrating google CAF into a custom iOS framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am trying to integrate Google CAF into my custom player sdk (`player.framework`). I tried following the documentation and was able to compile my `player.framework` successfully, however integration of player framework ends up in following linker error: -

```
*ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*
```

Error is mostly because of **ProtoBuf** library.

I tried using both ways, `cocoapods` and manual integration, getting same error in both the cases.
My custom player framework supports following architecture: -

```
armv7, armv7s, arm64, arm64e
```

I tried Umbrella framework approach too, but same result. Please help me in understanding the actual issue and what could be the possible solution.

With manual integration if I remove `armv7` architecture I was able to compile the Application (integrating `player.framework`), but `GoogleCast` delegates were never called.

Everything works as expected if I integrate CAF directly in the iOS app and not through `player.framework`.

TIA.

## Updating logs: -

```
## Entry #32: Query function for service ID 33 did not return PCStatus_UnknownQueryID for unknown name.
## Entry #32: Query function for service ID 33 did not return PCStatus_Success for query name exist.
## Entry #32: Query function for service ID 33 did not return PCStatus_Success for query name version.
## Entry #32: Query function for service ID 33 did not return PCStatus_Success for query name unittest.
## Entry #32: Query function for service ID 33 did not return PCStatus_Success for query name hasstrings.
2019-04-22 15:36:41.533340+0530[1452:666015] GoogleCast framework version 4.3.5.13
2019-04-22 15:36:41.672432+0530[1452:666015] [framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0
```

Comment: You are not able to integrate one framework into another. You should use cocoapods and set in podspec dependency from google-cast-sdk.

Comment: Hello Priyank , I agree with Cy-4AH you should set podspec dependency from google-cast sdk.

Comment: @Cy-4AH, I am not distributing player.framework library using Cocoapods.

Comment: @AnjaneeshRayapati, Do we have detailed documentation for manual integration of CAF, I am facing issues with protobuf.framework integration. I tried following the link given under sender's app documentation, but still getting same architecture error.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing we have is the manual setup section here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/#google_cast_sdk

If we understand correctly you are not trying to add it to an app, but trying to distribute it with your framework. We do not provide support for integrating the SDK into another framework.

Can you please let us know what specific errors you are seeing, may be we can assist if we know what is wrong with the compilation.

Please do file a bug using Cast Issue Tracker with all the necessary details and we will see what we can do to help you with this.
https://developers.google.com/cast/support

Comment: There's no compilation error, however I am facing linker error with architecture `armv7` and `armv7s` (for `Protobuf.framwork`). After removing these two architectures from Valid Architectures linker error is gone, however I am unable to get **kGCKCastStateDidChangeNotification**. (updated logs as well)